# What is wrong with my date format?

Tags: android, date, calendar

I am trying to get the date in this format "time":"05:09pm 08/02/2011". What I have so far is

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "HH:mmaa MM/dd/yyyy");

                holder.put("time", sdf.format(c.getTime()));
```

and this is what comes out.

```
                "time":"21:28PM 08\/26\/2011"
```

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it? Thanks

Comment: What is `holder` - where is the text "coming out" like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you want a format of

```
hh:mmaa MM/dd/yyyy
```

As `hh` is the 12-hour format in the range 01-12. I find that's typically how humans represent 12-hour values. Of course if you want 00-11, use KK instead as suggested by MByD.

(Quite what the rationale is for the capitalized form being the 24-hour version of HH, but the lower case form being the 24-hour version of kk, I don't know...)

If you were worried by the backslashes in the output, I suspect that's just JSON-escaping. I'm surprised it's necessary for forward-slashes, but it shouldn't do any harm.

Comment: yea, I was concerned about the forward slashes. Is there anything I can do to remove them from the JSON because I feel like thats whats messing up my program

Comment: @Sean: You *feel* like that, or you've *proved* it? What's parsing the data later? Note that it's not SimpleDateFormat which is putting in the backslash - it'll be whatever "holder" is.

Comment: JSONObject holder = new JSONObject(); My problem right now is that I send in the date that looks like "time":"10:28PM 08\/26\/2011" When I try to use another JSON post function to retrieve the date it comes out as "time":"07:14 PM 01/18/2038" Which doesnt make sense and I'm trying to figure out what is going on

Comment: @Sean: You talk about "sending in the date" - what to?

Comment: Im creating a JSON to send to a webserver that accepts the parameters "time","time_since_epoch",latitude and longitude. Since the only parameter that looked wrong when I put it into the JSON object was the date, I figured I was doing something wrong. If the backslashes aren't doing any harm and theres no way around it then its not something I have to worry about

Comment: @Sean: Given that they're being produced by a JSON object, I wouldn't *expect* it to be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `HH:mmaa MM/dd/yyyy` to `KK:mmaa MM/dd/yyyy`. (`KK` is hour in am/pm, 0-11)